# Which function do I need in my wordpress theme? query_posts(), get_posts(), get_post()

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on a **wordpress theme** and my homepage consists of 3 parts (see attached picture):

1. 4 featured **pages** section (red)
2. 3 featured **posts** section with 'news' as post category (orange)
3. 3 featured **posts** section with 'blog' as post category (blue)

The 3th section is displayed on all pages of my website as a sidebar.

I want to know if I am using a correct way to query data in wordpress, to get the needed data/content like page title, page thumbnail, post title etc...

I read it is not recommended to use query_post() so I was wondering what the correct way is.
Please don't look at the html, my question is just about the php. 
**It is important to know that my code does work, so I don't have error's.**

**My code to get the data to use in the 1st section (red):**

```
<div id="hiContainer">
                    <?php $i = 1;
                    query_posts( 'posts_per_page=4&cat=3' );
                    if ( have_posts() ) { 
                        while ( have_posts() ) {
                            the_post();
                            if ( $i < 4 ) { 
                                echo '<div class="headerItem">';
                            } 
                            else {
                                echo '<div id="hiLast">';
                            }
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                the_post_thumbnail( 'hiThumb' ); 
                            }
                    ?>
                            <div class="hiTitle">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </div>  
                    <?php   echo '</div>';
                            $i += 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else { 
                        echo '<p>';
                        _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );
                        echo '</p>';
                    }
                    ?>                      
                </div>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**My code to get the data to use in the 2nd section (orange):**

```
<div id="niContainer">
                <?php 
                query_posts( 'posts_per_page=3&cat=5' );
                if ( have_posts() ) { 
                    while( have_posts() ) {
                        the_post();             
                        echo '<div class="newsItem">';
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            echo '<div class="niImage">';
                                the_post_thumbnail( 'niThumb' ); 
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                ?>
                        <div class="niTitle">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="niExcerpt">
                            <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="niReadMore">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Lees meer <span style="color:#c73f20;">&#187;</span></a>
                        </div>
                <?php   
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                }
                ?>  
                </div>
```

**My code to get data to use in 3th section (blue):**

```
for ( $i = 1; $i < 4; $i++ ) {
                        $post_id = ot_get_option( 'post'.$i );
                        $post = get_post($post_id);
                        $author_id = $post->post_author;
                        $author_first_name = get_the_author_meta( 'first_name', $author_id );
                        $author_last_name = get_the_author_meta( 'last_name', $author_id );
                        echo '<div class="rsbPost">';
                                echo '<div class="rsbpThumb">'; 
                                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id ,'rsbpThumb' );
                                echo '</div>';
                            echo '<div class="rsbpTitle">';
                                echo '<a href="'; 
                                echo get_permalink( $post_id ); 
                                echo '"title="'; 
                                echo $post->post_title;
                                echo '">'; 
                                echo $post->post_title;
                                echo'</a>';
                            echo '</div>';
                            echo '<div class="rsbpMeta">';
                                if ( !empty( $author_first_name ) || !empty( $author_last_name ) ) {
                                    echo $author_first_name . " " . $author_last_name;
                                }
                                else {
                                    echo 'Redactie';
                                }                               
                                echo ', ';
                                echo mysql2date('j F Y', $post->post_date);
                            echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';          
                }
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer by Nathan and there's more to learn here: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to avoid using `query_posts()`. There's a warning about exactly that on the codex page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

So given that what is the solution?

New instances of WP_Query. It works almost exactly the way you've been doing it.

```
$section1 = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'cat'            => 3,
) );
```

You can find out more about the possible arguments here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Then replacing your current loop you would do:

```
if ( $section1->have_posts() ) : while ( $section1->have_posts() ) : $section1->the_post();
```

I named it section 1 but it would be wise to use a more appropriate name. `$header_posts` for example.

Create 3 instances for your three areas.

To take this a step further you could build this into home.php / index.php / front-page.php rather than setting the homepage to a static page. Then modify the main query (area marked as 2) using the `pre_get_posts` filter but that's outside the scope of your question.

Comment: I forgot to add something important, namely the fact that my section 3 does not use a wordpress loop, but instead of that displays 3 posts chosen by the admin in option tree in the backend.  So is my approach right because I am using get_post() in this section?

Comment: I am not sure if your suggestion about the static page is useful, since section 1 is part of my header.php, section 2 is part of index.php and section 3 is part of sidebar.php. Do you think it is still usefull?

Comment: Yes, it's still useful. My assumption about the placement of your loops was incorrect but the concept is still valid. If you don't use `pre_get_posts` the homepage gets the posts then you tell it to get another set of posts. It runs 2 queries for one loop therefore it's inefficient. Using `pre_get_posts` means you can modify the post query before it's run avoiding the need to run another query.

Comment: So in case I want to use wp_query without pre_get_posts I have to create a new wp_query object, each time I want to get content from te database? So when I need data in for example single.php, I have to create a new wp_query object and loop trough, right?